# why using alpha and beta as symbols causes sympy to give an error?

Tags: python, sympy

I am not very familiar with sympy, but when using alpha and beta as symbols in an integrated command it gives an error?  Here is an example. Using 1.12 sympy with Python 3.11.3

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> A,B,a,alpha,b,beta,x= symbols('A B a alpha b beta x ')
>>> integrate(S("(B*x+A)/(b*x+a)**(1/2)"),x)
```

No problem, gives

```
Piecewise(((2*A*sqrt(a + b*x) + 2*B*(-a*sqrt(a + b*x) + (a + b*x)**(3/2)/3)/b)/b, Ne(b, 0)), ((A*x + B*x**2/2)/sqrt(a), True))
```

But when changing `B,A` to `beta,alpha` it gives error

```
>>> integrate(S("(beta*x+alpha)/(b*x+a)**(1/2)"),x)
```

gives

```
ValueError: Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "(beta *Symbol ('x' )+Symbol ('alpha' ))/(Symbol ('b' )*Symbol ('x' )+Symbol ('a' ))**(Integer (1 )/Integer (2 ))"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 495, in sympify
    expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 1087, in parse_expr
    raise e from ValueError(f"Error from parse_expr with transformed code: {code!r}")
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 1078, in parse_expr
    rv = eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py", line 906, in eval_expr
    expr = eval(
           ^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'FunctionClass' and 'Symbol'
>>>
```

I searched to see if `beta` and `alpha` have special meaning or use in sympy, but so far I could not find anything.

These integrals are from external source. I did not write them myself and this is how they are in original form.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the conflict is caused by [sympy.functions.special.beta_functions.beta](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.beta_functions.beta), which happens to be of 'FunctionClass' type, like in the error. You could do

```
integrate(S("(Symbol('beta')*x)"))
```

which will ensure that beta will be parsed as a sympy Symbol and not as a sympy function of the same name.

```
>>> integrate(S("(Symbol('beta')*x+Symbol('alpha'))/(b*x+a)**(1/2)"),x)
Piecewise(((2*alpha*sqrt(a + b*x) + 2*beta*(-a*sqrt(a + b*x) + (a + b*x)**(3/2)/3)/b)/b, Ne(b, 0)), ((alpha*x + beta*x**2/2)/sqrt(a), True))
```

Using `Symbol('alpha')` over `alpha` doesn't seem to be necessary, but looks a bit more consistent this way.

Comment: I see. But this is strange  because when I was searching, on this [page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html)  it says explicitly `You can also import common symbol names from sympy.abc.` and then shows output of `dir(sympy.abc) ` showing `alpha` and `beta` listed as one of the common symbol names?  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcpkN.png)

Comment: I guess this case is covered by the note under that: `If you want control over the assumptions of the variables, use Symbol and symbols().` I'm guessing it would be a good practice to Symbol('') any potentially dubious names, since `gamma` would cause a similar conflict: `type(gamma)` returns `<class 'sympy.core.function.FunctionClass'>
`. I'm not sure if there's any docs or standards on this topic to point you to though, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `beta` is a function in SymPy:

```
In [3]: import sympy

In [4]: sympy.beta(3.0)
Out[4]: 0.0333333333333333

In [5]: sympy.S('beta(3.0)')
Out[5]: 0.0333333333333333
```

You can avoid this by passing the `locals` argument to specify that `beta` should be a Symbol:

```
In [9]: sympy.S('beta + alpha', locals={'beta':sympy.Symbol('beta')})
Out[9]: α + β
```